# Having issue loading content using Ajax

Tags: php, html, mysql, ajax, html-table

I currently adding an auto reload function in my page to allow user to see the new content without refreshing whole page. This is the first time I'm using Ajax, do advise me if my codes are put at the wrong place.

This is my page's view:

[image]

This is what happen when my ajax code reload the content:

[image]

The reloaded data doesn't enter into the table cell.

This is how I call the table content from database and refreshing it every 30sec:

```
<?php include 'connectdb.php';
$result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT tbluser.userId, tblorder.userId, tblorder.id, tblorder.from, tblorder.to, tblorder.itemCat, tblorder.itemName, tblorder.quantity, tblorder.size, tblorder.weight, tblorder.date FROM tbluser, tblorder WHERE tbluser.userId=tblorder.userId and tbluser.userLvlId='4'") or die ("Data not found !");
while ($rows =mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {

    $orderid = $rows['id'];
    $userid = $rows['userId'];
    $from = $rows['from'];
    $to = $rows['to'];
    $itemCat = $rows['itemCat'];
    $itemName = $rows['itemName'];
    $quantity = $rows['quantity'];
    $size = $rows['size'];
    $weight = $rows['weight'];
    $date = $rows['date'];

    ?>

    <tr>
        <td align="center" valign="middle"><?php echo $rows['id']; ?></td>
        <td align="center" valign="middle"><?php echo $rows['userId']; ?></td>
        <td align="center" valign="middle"><?php echo $rows['from']; ?></td>
        <td align="center" valign="middle"><?php echo $rows['to']; ?></td>
        <td align="center" valign="middle"><?php echo $rows['itemCat']; ?></td>
        <td align="center" valign="middle"><?php echo $rows['itemName']; ?></td>
        <td align="center" valign="middle"><?php echo $rows['quantity']; ?></td>
        <td align="center" valign="middle"><?php echo $rows['size']; ?></td>
        <td align="center" valign="middle"><?php echo $rows['weight']; ?></td>
        <td align="center" valign="middle"><?php echo $rows['date']; ?></td>
        <td align="center" valign="middle"><a href="edit order.php?userId=<?php  print htmlentities($userid); ?>"><input type="button" value="EDIT" style="width:50px; height:30px; font-size:10px; text-align: center; padding-left:10px; padding-top:8px;"></a></td>
    </tr>
    <?php
}
?>

<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.12.3.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function() {
        setInterval(function () {
        $('#loadhere').load('ordertable.php')
      }, 30000);
    });
```

This is my html file :

```
<div id="content">
        <div id="table">
            <div id="title">
                <a>ORDER DETAILS</a>
            </div>
            <table id="data" border="2" style=" margin: 0 auto; color:#3b3b3b;" >
    <?php include 'ordertable.php'; ?>

  <thead>
    <tr>
    <div style="height:10px;"></div>
     <th>&nbsp;&nbsp;ORDER ID&nbsp;&nbsp;</th>
      <th>&nbsp;&nbsp;USER ID&nbsp;&nbsp;</th>
      <th>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;FROM (LOCATION)&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</th>
      <th>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;TO (DESTINATION)&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</th>
      <th>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;CATEGORY&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</th>
      <th>&nbsp;&nbsp;ITEM NAME&nbsp;&nbsp;</th>
      <th>&nbsp;QUANTITY&nbsp;</th>
      <th>&nbsp;SIZE&nbsp;</th>
      <th>&nbsp;WEIGHT&nbsp;</th>
      <th>&nbsp;DATE&nbsp;</th>
      <th>EDIT</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>

  <tbody>
    <div id="loadhere">

    </div>
</tbody>
</table>
          </div>
        </div>
```

Do ask me for more details if you're not clear what my problem was.

Comment: where is your ajax code?

Comment: I thought the javascript in my code is the ajax code ? @RuchishParikh

Comment: If you want to use `$row['id']` in `td` tag then why are you storing its value in variable `$orderrid` and same for other like `user_id, from, to etc`

Comment: Thanks for your advise, i have done the changes. @User7

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're trying to set a div in a table, that's not possible. You can solve it to change this:

```
<tbody>
    <div id="loadhere">
    </div>
</tbody>
```

To

```
<tbody id="loadhere">
    //Here goes all the <tr><td></td></tr> etc
</tbody>
```

Change your JavaScript code to

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    setInterval(function () {
        $.get("ordertable.php", function(data) {
            $("#loadhere").html(data);
        });
    }, 30000);
});
```

Hope this works!

Comment: Thanks for your help,my array data is now display correctly in the table cell. But my content is now duplicated. @Robin Dirksen

Comment: @ChiYang I edited the post a little bit, hope this works!